# Loading a simple Qt Designer form in to Pyside

Tags: python, qt4, pyside

I create a simple form in Qt designer and am trying to load it in to a Qt application I'm creating with PySide but without much luck.

Here's the generated code from `pyside-uic':

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'clientEditorForm.ui'
#
# Created: Tue Nov  3 23:46:41 2009
#      by: PySide uic UI code generator
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PySide import QtCore, QtGui

class Ui_clientEditorForm(object):
    def setupUi(self, clientEditorForm):
        clientEditorForm.setObjectName("clientEditorForm")
        clientEditorForm.resize(575, 446)
        self.horizontalLayout_3 = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(clientEditorForm)
        self.horizontalLayout_3.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_3")
        self.splitter = QtGui.QSplitter(clientEditorForm)
        self.splitter.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.splitter.setObjectName("splitter")
        self.layoutWidget = QtGui.QWidget(self.splitter)
        self.layoutWidget.setObjectName("layoutWidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self.layoutWidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_2")
        self.searchLabel = QtGui.QLabel(self.layoutWidget)
        self.searchLabel.setObjectName("searchLabel")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.searchLabel)
        self.searchEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.layoutWidget)
        self.searchEdit.setObjectName("searchEdit")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.searchEdit)
        self.clearButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.clearButton.setObjectName("clearButton")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.clearButton)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_2)
        self.clientListView = QtGui.QListView(self.layoutWidget)
        sizePolicy = QtGui.QSizePolicy(QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.clientListView.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.clientListView.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.clientListView.setObjectName("clientListView")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.clientListView)
        self.frame = QtGui.QFrame(self.splitter)
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QtGui.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtGui.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame.setObjectName("frame")
        self.verticalLayout_3 = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self.frame)
        self.verticalLayout_3.setObjectName("verticalLayout_3")
        self.formLayout = QtGui.QFormLayout()
        self.formLayout.setObjectName("formLayout")
        self.nameEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.frame)
        self.nameEdit.setObjectName("nameEdit")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(0, QtGui.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.nameEdit)
        self.nameLabel = QtGui.QLabel(self.frame)
        self.nameLabel.setObjectName("nameLabel")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(0, QtGui.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.nameLabel)
        self.profileButton = QtGui.QLabel(self.frame)
        self.profileButton.setObjectName("profileButton")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(1, QtGui.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.profileButton)
        self.addressLabel = QtGui.QLabel(self.frame)
        self.addressLabel.setObjectName("addressLabel")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(2, QtGui.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.addressLabel)
        self.locationLabel = QtGui.QLabel(self.frame)
        self.locationLabel.setObjectName("locationLabel")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(3, QtGui.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.locationLabel)
        self.secureLabel = QtGui.QLabel(self.frame)
        self.secureLabel.setObjectName("secureLabel")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(4, QtGui.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.secureLabel)
        self.UUIDLabel = QtGui.QLabel(self.frame)
        self.UUIDLabel.setObjectName("UUIDLabel")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(5, QtGui.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.UUIDLabel)
        self.passwordLabel = QtGui.QLabel(self.frame)
        self.passwordLabel.setObjectName("passwordLabel")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(6, QtGui.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.passwordLabel)
        self.profileComboBox = QtGui.QComboBox(self.frame)
        self.profileComboBox.setObjectName("profileComboBox")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(1, QtGui.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.profileComboBox)
        self.addressEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.frame)
        self.addressEdit.setObjectName("addressEdit")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(2, QtGui.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.addressEdit)
        self.locationComboBox = QtGui.QComboBox(self.frame)
        self.locationComboBox.setObjectName("locationComboBox")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(3, QtGui.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.locationComboBox)
        self.secureComboBox = QtGui.QComboBox(self.frame)
        self.secureComboBox.setObjectName("secureComboBox")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(4, QtGui.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.secureComboBox)
        self.UUIDEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.frame)
        self.UUIDEdit.setObjectName("UUIDEdit")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(5, QtGui.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.UUIDEdit)
        self.passwordEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.frame)
        self.passwordEdit.setObjectName("passwordEdit")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(6, QtGui.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.passwordEdit)
        self.verticalLayout_3.addLayout(self.formLayout)
        self.aliasesGroupBox = QtGui.QGroupBox(self.frame)
        self.aliasesGroupBox.setFlat(False)
        self.aliasesGroupBox.setCheckable(False)
        self.aliasesGroupBox.setObjectName("aliasesGroupBox")
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self.aliasesGroupBox)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
        self.aliasesListView = QtGui.QListView(self.aliasesGroupBox)
        self.aliasesListView.setObjectName("aliasesListView")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.aliasesListView)
        self.horizontalLayout_4 = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_4.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_4")
        spacerItem = QtGui.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout_4.addItem(spacerItem)
        self.addButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.aliasesGroupBox)
        self.addButton.setObjectName("addButton")
        self.horizontalLayout_4.addWidget(self.addButton)
        self.removeButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.aliasesGroupBox)
        self.removeButton.setObjectName("removeButton")
        self.horizontalLayout_4.addWidget(self.removeButton)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_4)
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.aliasesGroupBox)
        spacerItem1 = QtGui.QSpacerItem(20, 38, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.verticalLayout_3.addItem(spacerItem1)
        self.horizontalLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        spacerItem2 = QtGui.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout.addItem(spacerItem2)
        self.revertButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.frame)
        self.revertButton.setObjectName("revertButton")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.revertButton)
        self.applyButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.frame)
        self.applyButton.setObjectName("applyButton")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.applyButton)
        self.verticalLayout_3.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout)
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.splitter)
        self.searchLabel.setBuddy(self.searchEdit)
        self.nameLabel.setBuddy(self.nameEdit)
        self.profileButton.setBuddy(self.profileComboBox)
        self.addressLabel.setBuddy(self.addressEdit)
        self.locationLabel.setBuddy(self.locationComboBox)
        self.secureLabel.setBuddy(self.secureComboBox)
        self.UUIDLabel.setBuddy(self.UUIDEdit)
        self.passwordLabel.setBuddy(self.passwordEdit)

        self.retranslateUi(clientEditorForm)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(clientEditorForm)

    def retranslateUi(self, clientEditorForm):
        clientEditorForm.setWindowTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("clientEditorForm", "Form", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.searchLabel.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("clientEditorForm", "Search", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.clearButton.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("clientEditorForm", "Clear", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.nameLabel.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("clientEditorForm", "Name", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.profileButton.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("clientEditorForm", "Profile", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.addressLabel.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("clientEditorForm", "Address", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.locationLabel.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("clientEditorForm", "Location", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.secureLabel.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("clientEditorForm", "Secure", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.UUIDLabel.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("clientEditorForm", "UUID", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.passwordLabel.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("clientEditorForm", "Password", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.aliasesGroupBox.setTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("clientEditorForm", "Aliases", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.addButton.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("clientEditorForm", "Add", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.removeButton.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("clientEditorForm", "Remove", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.revertButton.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("clientEditorForm", "Revert", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.applyButton.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("clientEditorForm", "Apply", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
```

Then my simple application:

```
import sys
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui

from clientEditorForm import Ui_clientEditorForm

class MyMainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyMainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.ui = Ui_clientEditorForm()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MyMainWindow()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

However, when I try to run it, I get the following:

```
QLayout: Attempting to add QLayout "" to QMainWindow "clientEditorForm", which already has a layout
```

and a segmentation fault. I'm following the basic instructions in [this tutorial](http://www.rkblog.rk.edu.pl/w/p/introduction-pyqt4/) but I can't tell what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7684975/pyqt4-qt-designer-making-dynamic-guis

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out there is a bug in PySide with the QSpacerItem class. Commenting out the QSpacerItem instances in the code above makes it work just fine. There's a bug report on the [PySide bugzilla](http://bugs.openbossa.org/show_bug.cgi?id=92).

Answer (score 4):

Firstly you are using PySide(Nokia) not PyQt4(Riverbank Computing), although their API's are nearly identical they are not the same project. The PySide examples are available here:
git clone git://gitorious.org/pyside/pyside-examples.git

I think the problem may have to do with your call of

```
super(MyMainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
```

try

```
QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
```

instead.

I know it seems like it is the same thing, but I've ran into similar problems with super using PyQt4, and from what I can tell Nokia's PySide has the same troubles. It has something to do with weather the Python owns the parent or it's owned by an underlying C++ object. At least give it a try, it'll take less than 5 seconds!

Below is the example I'm basing this off of, it's from the git repo for PySide.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

#############################################################################
##
## Copyright (C) 2004-2005 Trolltech AS. All rights reserved.
##
## This file is part of the example classes of the Qt Toolkit.
##
## This file may be used under the terms of the GNU General Public
## License version 2.0 as published by the Free Software Foundation
## and appearing in the file LICENSE.GPL included in the packaging of
## this file.  Please review the following information to ensure GNU
## General Public Licensing requirements will be met:
## http://www.trolltech.com/products/qt/opensource.html
##
## If you are unsure which license is appropriate for your use, please
## review the following information:
## http://www.trolltech.com/products/qt/licensing.html or contact the
## sales department at sales@trolltech.com.
##
## This file is provided AS IS with NO WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, INCLUDING THE
## WARRANTY OF DESIGN, MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
##
#############################################################################

import sys
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui

from ui_calculatorform import Ui_CalculatorForm


class CalculatorForm(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        self.ui = Ui_CalculatorForm()

        self.ui.setupUi(self)

    @QtCore.pyqtSignature("int")
    def on_inputSpinBox1_valueChanged(self, value):
        self.ui.outputWidget.setText(QtCore.QString.number(value + self.ui.inputSpinBox2.value()))

    @QtCore.pyqtSignature("int")
    def on_inputSpinBox2_valueChanged(self, value):
        self.ui.outputWidget.setText(QtCore.QString.number(value + self.ui.inputSpinBox1.value()))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    calculator = CalculatorForm()
    calculator.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```