# PyQt4 Qt Designer making dynamic GUIs

Tags: pyqt4, qt-designer

I'm trying to figure out a way of using Qt Designer to make a dynamic GUI.  For example, let's say I have a main window with a horizontal layout. I have a push button on one side and an empty area on the other.  When I click the button the empty area will be filled with a widget that I've made in Qt Designer.  When the button is pressed again the widget will be replaced with another widget that I've made in Qt Designer.  Would I have to go about making all my widgets, to fill the empty area, custom widgets?

I've tried setting the parent to the empty are, but on the second change I get this

```
QLayout: Attempting to add QLayout "" to QWidget "t2", which already has a layout
```

So then I tried deleting the layout but still see the old widget underneath the new one and the layout is now messed up.

help please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never mind, figured it out.  Simple really.  Use QStackedWidget and as for the UIs made in Qt Designer wrap that in a class that inherits from QWidget.

Comment: Had the same problem with something similar in PySide. What helped me in the answer was :  wrap in a class that inherits from QWidget. Thanks